# How to use Azure Pipelines to run command on Remote Server but not in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: ssh, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, ubuntu-server

I would like to use Azure Pipelines to call *Open XLTerminal* in Remote Ubuntu Server (called **ServerYYY**).

a) In Releases in Azure Pipelines, I tried to add "Deployment Group Job" task (which I followed [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-linuxvm-deploygroups?view=azure-devops&tabs=java-script#define-your-ci-build-pipeline) to perform)

1. Create Bash Task with Inline script `lxterminal --title="MyScriptWindow"` but having error:

   > (lxterminal:26865): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:36:56.947: cannot open display:

b) In Releases in Azure Pipelines, I tried to add "Agent Job" task

1. Create SSH Task to connect **ServerYYY** with Inline script `lxterminal --title="MyScriptWindow"`

   > same error as above

How can I run task to open *Open XLTerminal* so that when I remote to **ServerYYY**, I can see the Teminal opening?

Comment: Do you check X11Forwarding is enabled in the remote host's /etc/ssh/ssh_config

Comment: After I uncomment in ssh_config to set `ForwardAgent yes`, `ForwardX11 yes` & `ForwardX11Trusted yes` then restart Ubuntu Server to make is effective, I still fave same error in Azure Pipelines.